# How to deploy a WCF Service in a specific web application

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have created a WCF service, and in visual studio, I just right-click the project and deployed it.

It was deployed globally, I can access it in any of my web app (http://webapp1/_vti_bin/WCF.svc/mex and http://webapp2/_vti_bin/WCF.svc/mex)

How can I configure it so that I would only be able to access it using webapp1?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cant' deploy it to just a specific web application if you go the 12/14 hive destionation.

You can check in the current context site collection for a specific custom "flag" feature that you will create is activated or not and only allow the access / processing of the WCF service if the targeted feature is activated.

You can make a hidden site collection feature and activate it on the relevant site collection(s) so that other site collections won't be able to use it by just turning on the feature.

Kindly.

Edit : as alternate solution, you can check based on any recognized path of the web application to have a whitelist. Be carefull with AAM / binding in that case because the web app can be accessed using a bunch of urls !

Comment: I copied my dll and wsp files and try to add it to the other server using 

• Add-SPSolution c:\deploy\<solution file>.wsp
Afterwhich, I deploy it using 

• Install-SPSolution –Identity <solution file>.wsp –WebApplication http://<url> -GACDeployment

But there is an error: 

Install-SPSolution : This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web application and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application.

I removed the -WebApplication parameter and it worked but I can access it using any web application. What I want to do is to only access it on a specific web app.